# How to get data from a specific date in sql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am trying to get the **data** of the **current date** in MySQL. I have a column named **`created_at`** which stores the date and time `(2017-12-31 11:32:54)`using the **`NOW()`** function using the statements,

```
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO log(id, name, created_at) VALUES(?, ?, NOW())");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $id, $name);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
```

Now I want to ignore the **time** in the **`created_at`** column and retrieve the data of the current date (today's date).

I tried using this query,

```
SELECT * FROM log WHERE created_at = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY)
```

But this results in `zero rows selected`.

Please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option would be to wrap `created_at` with `DATE()`, and then compare to `CURDATE()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM log
WHERE DATE(created_at) = CURDATE();
```

But this has the drawback of precluding the possibility of using an index on the `created_at` column.  We could also phrase this as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM log
WHERE created_at >= CURDATE() AND created_at < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

This would allow an index to be used on `created_at`, though it is a bit more verbose.

Comment: Thank you, it works but what do you mean by using an index?

Comment: @VishistVVishy If you had an index on the `created_at` column, it would not be available to use in a query if you had something like `DATE(created_at)`, i.e. if you wrapped it in a function.  My second query gets around this potential problem.

Answer (score 2):

---

this will also work

```
SELECT *
FROM log
WHERE  DATE(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d')  = CURDATE();
```